# How's product moment generating function different from moment generating function?

Tags: moments, moment-generating-function

I have a reference that gives an example of a Poisson "product moment generating function":

$$G(t)=E(t^X)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}t^i\frac{\theta^i}{n!}e^{-\theta}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\theta t)^i}{n!}e^{-\theta}=e^{\theta t}e^{-\theta}=e^{-\theta(1-t)}$$

Is this a common concept, since I only find "moment generating function" and how's this different from moment generating function? Specifically, why is there the $n!$ and not $i!$ (as per the p.d.f of Poisson) in the denominator?

Comment: This is more commonly called "probability generating function"

Answer (score 5):

This is called the [probability generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function). The relationship between the pgf and mgf is:

$G_X(e^t) = M_X(t)$, where

- $G_X(t) := E[t^X]$
- $M_X(t) := E[e^{tX}]$